# Wordpress div should appear only in one page but it appears everywhere

Tags: wordpress

I have problem in wordpress. When I add div with input in single-episode.php it should appear only in EPISODE page but, this div appears in every page in my theme.

```
<div id="ciul">
    
    
    
    <Script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/vodi/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"> </script>
    
    
      <input type="submit" id="wyslij" name="przycisk" value="<?php echo $checkboxstatus;?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

   jQuery("#wyslij").click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      checkboxstatus = "<?php echo $checkboxstatus; ?>";
      

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         
         url : "czekboks.php",
         data : {checkboxstatus:checkboxstatus},
         success: function(result) {
                console.log('the data was successfully sent to the server');
            }

      })   

   })

})
</script>
    




</div>
```

Comment: There isn't mush to go on here. This has most likely nothing to do with the div itself, but how this template is referenced in the theme. Is this a custom post type or a widget or what is it really?

Comment: Try to add details, post the full content from the single-episode.php, don't hesitate to over explain your issue, we're not next to you.

Comment: Its just normal template file with functions. I dont know much, so its hard to say. Sorry for my 2 iq head.

Comment: The code is too long : |